# Почему разный отступ на страницах, хотя классы применяю одни и те же?

Tags: html, css

На странице https://4coders.pro/Unbrokenteam/pages/legal-services.html отступ от левого края уже, чем на странице https://4coders.pro/Unbrokenteam/, хотя и там, и там одинаковые классы

HTML ([index.html](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/UE37/ao99vBRJJ), [legal-services.html](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/8NyP/s5FDX9BYQ)):

```html
<div class="text-padding"><div class="myDivWhiteBackground"><div class="grey">
<div class="text_padding"><div class="myDivBlueBackground"><div class="grey">
```

[style.css:](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/1BWM/j4KbZBhdd)

```css
.myDivBlueBackground{
      background-color: #FEE3B0;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .myDivWhiteBackground{
      background-color: white;
      padding: 20px;
    }

 .text_padding{
      padding-left: 25px;
    }

 .grey {
      color: #7F7F7F;
    }
```

Почему разный отступ на страницах, классы применяю же одни и те же?

Comment: Потому что на странице с отступом есть div с классом `text_padding`, а странице без отступа его нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опечатка в названии класса div class="text-padding", должно быть text_padding

Comment: Спасибо! Точно, не заметил